# How to get an element that has a jquery .data('index') applied to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am setting an element's data attribute onclick of it to the current index, of the element... for example, take the following html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="get-me">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="alink">Click Me</a> <input type="text" value="" name="name1" />
    </li>
    <li class="get-me">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="alink">Click Me</a> <input type="text" value="" name="name2" />
    </li>
    <li class="not-me">
        <input type="text" value="A value" name="aName" readonly />
    </li>
    <li class="get-me">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="alink">Click Me</a> <input type="text" value="" name="name3" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, onclick, of the `a.alink` links I add `data('index')` to each input sibling... example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.alink').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            $input = $this.next('input');

        if ($input.length)
        {
            $('.alink').each(function(i, obj) {
                if (obj == $this.eq(0))
                {
                    $(obj).next('input').data('index', i);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now the order of these li's can change, after the links have been clicked on, but the `jQuery.data` stays the same, so wondering if it's possible to get input element that has `.data('index') == 1` somehow, as a jQuery object element (like `$(this)`)?  I know that it's possible if the data attribute existed, but this is not the case as it's being set in code instead.  And I'm wondering if this can be selected directly instead of looping through all `input` elements and checking their `.data('index')` properties.

**EDIT**

So I have split this into a function here:

```
function inputFilter(selector, index)
{
    var obj = null;

    if (selector.trim() !== '')
    {
        obj = $(selector).filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('index') == index;
        });
    }
    return obj;
}
```

But trying to use it returns all input elements:

`var $object = inputFilter('input', 1);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(obj == this)` is always evaluate to true

Comment: Don't use `href="javascript:void(0)"`. That's how things were done in the previous century, and I'm not even joking. Use jQuery's [`Event#preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent links from loading a page.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with setting those .data('index') ?

Comment: The issue here is that I am using thickbox to update an input element once from where it was called at once a save button is clicked inside of the thickbox.  But thickbox does not allow you to know which element triggered it when using ajax to load the thickbox, so I need to set the index in the href, which I can now manage with the ajax part of the thickbox, once the thickbox ajax is saved.

Comment: @Musa - I fixed the issues you and Tomalak mentioned.  This is right on my test, but I am writing an example quickly here.  The code I have will take too much time to edit, and I can't simply throw the code in here without editing it properly.  But this is the same as what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `.filter` function that looks for the data you want.

```
$('input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('index') == '1';
});
```

```js
function inputFilter(selector, index) {
  var obj = null;

  if (selector.trim() !== '') {
    obj = $(selector).filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('index') == index;
    });
  }
  return obj;
}

$("#input1").data("index", 1);
$("#input2").data("index", 3);

console.log(inputFilter('input', 1).map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">
<input id="input3">
```

Comment: I can't use `data` attribute, it must be set dynamically in code.

Comment: Then use the first part of the answer.

Comment: Your filter function doesn't seem to be working correctly... I set an example of it's use in my question.

Comment: Thanks, I had a different, unrelated issue that I resolved and once that was resolved, this worked a charm!  Thank You very much!